# How do I install an SSL certificate on Namecheap when it asks me to "Edit methods" for DNS validation?

Tags: dns, https, cname, namecheap, site-verification

[image]

I am at the screen above when adding SSL certificates for my domain in Namecheap, but I am completely lost on what to do next. I think it is saying to get a CNAME record, but there is no explicit record provided when clicking Get Record. What are the steps I can do next after this screen to install my SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, first do what it says: click on `Edit methods` -> `Get record`.

You need to copy the value of the `Host` field and go to `Domain list` -> Select your domain and click `Manage` -> `Advanced DNS` -> `ADD NEW RECORD` -> Select `CNAME RECORD` -> Paste the value of `Host` that you just copied on the `Host` field of the CNAME Record. Now, copy the `Target` field's value to the `Value` field in the CNAME Record.

**IMPORTANT:** When you paste the `Host` value in the CNAME Record remove the `.yourdomain.whatever` from the end of the field. And that's the important bit here, if you don't remove it, it won't work. Save your changes.

> Note: Some DNS systems(Namecheap system as well) have such peculiarity that they add domain name automatically to the values submitted during record creation.

More information can be found [here](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9637/68/how-can-i-complete-the-domain-control-validation-dcv-for-my-ssl-certificate/).

You can then check that your CNAME Record was added by using that website linked by them `mxtoolbox.com/...`. When you check the record, don't remove the `.yourdomain.whatever` part of the `Host` field.